# Mysql fetch data between two rows

Tags: mysql, select

Newbie question: 
I want to get data between two rows, say, row number 5 and row number 10. How can I do that?
There is no id or any integer column in the table and I cannot modify the table.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: If you want to talk about row numbers and rows between them, you have to specify how you order the rows. There is *no* natural  ordering on rows in MySQL.

Comment: @martijn: The answer by Harry Joy satisfied my needs. However, I will read more about ordering in MySQL. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use limit

```
select * from `table` limit 4,5;
```

Comment: I am a first time user. Moreover, there is a certain time limit before which you cannot upvote/accept an answer.